# Nigerian currency is not showing in fpdf

Tags: currency, fpdf

I want to show the Nigerian currency in my pdf using fpdf. But it not showing.Thanks in advance for any help.`$custom_currency = '₦';
$pdf->Cell(60,20,"  $custom_currency.'-'.$g_total",1 , 1, 'L', 1);`

Comment: Have you checked that the font you are using contains the nigerian currency symbol?

Comment: Yes, it is supported in Arial font that I used